# Problemas al recargar páginas. Angular 7 y Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5, php5, angular7

Tengo un inconveniente al subir mi proyecto al servidor. Se trata de una api restful realizada con Laravel 5.2 (Back-end) y Angular 7 (Front-end). 
Trabajando en forma local no tuve ningún problema, pero al subirlo, noto  que las páginas se muestran bien si clickeo en los botones, o elementos que realicen ruteos. Pero si en algunas de estas páginas intento refrescar (a excepción de la "index"), obtengo el siguiente error en pantalla.

```
Not Found
The requested URL /ianexo/web/login was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at arushap34 Port 80
```

Si alguien sabe como solucionarlo, por favor me avisa que código necesita que muestre para corregir. Desde ya les agradezco. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debido a que la aplicación utiliza el enrutamiento debes configurar el servidor para que siempre redirija al index.html. Esto lo haces escribiendo un archivo .htaccess con el siguiente contenido:

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Para una explicacion mas profunda revisa este link: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration

Comment: Agradezco tu ayuda, voy a probar implementar esta solución y te aviso como me fue. Saludos!

Comment: Anibal Ospina. Ya hemos implementado tu solución, y funciona a la perfección. No tengo más que agradecerte. Un abrazo.